# SWT Composite needs pack() in 3.6.1

Tags: java, swing, eclipse-plugin, swt

My wizard isn't rendering correctly in Eclipse 3.6.1. It's leading me to wonder: when does one have to use Composite.pack()? Some SWT examples have it, and some don't.

How my wizard pages renders depends on the target platform. If I run my plugins in 3.5.2, they render correctly as soon as I open them. But in 3.6.1, their contents areas are blank when they first one. The pages use GridLayout.

If I use the mouse to resize the wizard dialog, it immediately renders just fine.
If I call pack() on the control that I pass to DialogPage.setControl(), the page renders, but it's not quite wide enough. A subsequent resize fixes the width.

Can someone shed some light? Is there a general rule for when to use pack()?

(Tagged with Swing because experts there may have answers as well as SWTers.)

Answer (score 2):

`pack()` sets the size of the target to its default size. It is usually used on `Shell`s, as usually the parent's `Layout` is taking care of calling `setSize()` for the widgets it manages. You may be better off explicitly setting some `Layout` (e.g., `FillLayout`) on your `Composite`'s parent rather than call `pack()`.